# Show that if $f$ is a smooth function, $M$ is a manifold and $x$ is a local extremum of $f$ on $M$, then $D_f(x)(v) = 0$ in the tangent space.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, tangent-spaces

Let $M \subset R^n$ be a $k$ dimensional manifold. Let $f: R^n \to R$ be a smooth function. Let $x \in M$ be a local extremum of $f$ on $M$.

The task is to prove that $\nabla f_x (v) = 0$ for every $v \in T_xM$ (the tangent space at $x$).

I am not really sure fro where to start. What I find weird is that I remember that if $y$ is a local extremum of $f$, then $\nabla f_y = 0$ (it is the gradient at the point $y$). But then the question is trivial, so I am probably getting something wrong here.

Can some one show me what is the problem and give me a direction on how to solve it?
Help would be appreciated.

I also need to such an example of such a function so that $\nabla f_x \ne 0$.

Edit:
Let $M \subset R^n$ be a $k$-dimensional manifold and let $ f : R^n \to R$ be a smooth function s.t $ x_0 /in M $ is a local extremum point of $f$ on $M$

(i) Show that $\nabla f_{x_0}(h) = 0$ for every $h \in T_{x_0}M$.

(ii) Find such a function with $\nabla f{x_0} \ne 0$

Comment: In some local chart $g = f \circ \phi$ is just a smooth function with a local extrmum at $a=\phi^{-1}(x)$. That $g$ is $C^1$ means $g(a+tv) = g(a)+t D_v g(a)+o(t)$ where $D_v g(a) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{g(a+tv)-g(a)}{t}$ is the directional derivative. If $D_v g(a) \ne 0$ then $a$ can't be a local extremum. $D_vg(a)$ is linear in $v$. When changing of chart $v$ is sent to $Mv$ with $M$ the Jacobian of $\varphi^{-1} \phi$. The tangent space formalism is to make this basis and chart independent.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $v\in TM_x$. The function $g:t\mapsto f(x+tv)$ has an extremum at $t=0$ and since $g'(t)=\nabla f(x+tv)\cdot v,\ $ it follows that $0=g'(0)=\nabla f(x)\cdot v$ from which the claim follows.

For the second part, use the rank theorem: set $x=(x_1,\cdots, x_k, x_{k+1},\cdots, x_n)$. There are diffeomorphisms $\psi$ and $\phi$ such that

$\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}(x_1,\cdots, x_k, x_{k+1},\cdots, x_n)=(x_1,\cdots x_k, 0,\cdots, 0)$.

The gradient of this function at $x_0$ is $(\underbrace{1,1,\cdots,1}_{\text k},\underbrace{0,0,\cdots,0)}_{\text n-k}$, clearly non-zero, and the chain rule now shows that $\nabla f(x_0)\neq 0.$

Comment: Thanks! However, I am still not able to fully understand how can it be that $\nabla f(x) \ne 0$, since $x$ is an extremum point

Comment: So isn't the question trivial? Then how can I find an example such that $\nabla f(x) \ne 0$?

Comment: But in this example, I don't think $(0,0)$ is a local extremum

Comment: Then your example doesn't satisfy the conditions

Comment: But I want to find an example of $\nabla f(x) \ne 0$ and  $\nabla f(x) *v =0$ for every vector in the tangent space

Comment: Okay, just to be clear, I have managed to prove the first path, so now, given $M$ and $x_0$ I am looking for a smooth function $f$ such that $x_0 $ is an extremum point on $M$ (doesn't have to be an extremum on $R^n$) and it satisfies $\nabla f(x_0)v = 0$ while $\nabla f(x_0) \ne 0$

Comment: I am not really sure how to do it, since there are many conditions that are needed to be satisfied. Moreover, it needs to be about some general manifold $M$.

Comment: I have tried to think about something, but I still didn't manage to

Comment: Other than the point being this particular $x_0$ which is the extremum on $M$, everything else in general. Moreover, since $T_{x_0}M$ is equal to $ker\nabla f(x_0)$ , then $nabla f(x_0)$ is not necessarily the zero transformation

Comment: Now I think I see what you mean: you're taking level sets $S:= f^{-1}(\{c\})$, then curves $\gamma:t\mapsto S$ so that $f\circ (S)=c$ is constant, and therefore $f'(\gamma (0))v=0.$ where $\gamma'(0)=v\in TM_{\gamma (0)}.$ Then the kernel of $f'(\gamma(0))$ is the tangent space. And you want a manifold for which $f'(\gamma(0))$ is not zero. Is this what you mean? If this is so, I will delete my other comments.

Comment: I think that yes, that sounds about right

Comment: I am still not exactly sure what the question is, but if you take the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and a circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, intersect the curve with the surface and you get an ellipse on the paraboloid, for which there will be a maximum (and minimum). I think you can show that the  gradient at these points is non-zero. Why don't you copy/paste the exact question!

Comment: I added the exact question. The problem with your comment that they ask for it to be on some general manifold

Comment: by the rank theorem, there are diffeomorphisms $\phi$ and $\psi$ s.t. $\psi\circ f\circ \phi(x_0)=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k,0,0,\cdots 0).$ The gradient of this function is clearly non-zero, and this implies that the gradient of $f$ is also non-zero.